# How to run fastText model on google extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, fasttext

I am trying to integrate trained fastText model for text classification in Google Extension.

There are several fastText javascript wrapper like , but all of them running on node.js which is server-side while chrome extension to my knowledge runs on client-side

Are there any ways i can run prediction of model in Chrome Extension?

Thanks a lot

Comment: FastText is [written in C++](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/src) so you'll have to use a server or write a [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) wrapper.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate more on the server method? I am new to this.

Comment: I mean REST (or GraphQL) API implemented on a server you own or rent, which your extension queries by posting a request with XMLHttpRequest or jQuery.ajax or Fetch.

Comment: i have fasttext file (shared library file) that can do one-liner training and prediction on linux console. How can i load using nativeMessaging. Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: You'll have to study the documentation.

Comment: Thank you i will check it out

Comment: May i know which is the more straightforward way to do this? B/c i want to move on with other algorithm. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the C++ code can be compiled into js with EmScripten.